# error when trying to compile with clang

Tags: c++, terminal, clang++

I use Ubuntu 14 and try to compile a c++ program in the terminal. Until now I used g++ and compiling worked without problems. As I prefer the error messages from clang I want to work with clang++ from now on.

So far I used the command

```
g++ -oexec main.cpp file.cpp
```

but when I try

```
clang++ -oexec main.cpp file.cpp
```

I get the error

```
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

Comment: Are you sure Clang has the option "oexec" because googling for it gives me no results.

Comment: Are these the only options supplied to clang? Because this should work and generate an executable named `exec`. It does not work if you specify e.g. `-c`, because clang cannot collapse multiple source files into a single object.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I think you are also passing '-c' flag to the compiler while compiling with clang.

When you pass '-c', it will not work either with clang/gcc. This is because when you pass '-c' you are essentially saying that compile each file into object file (.o files), hence, providing '-o' in that case is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://gist.github.com/masuidrive/5231110) is a list of all Clang flags. As you can see "oexec" is not one of them. Instead Clang is reading your command as -o (Write output to ) and spits out the error, because you can't use -o when outputting to multiple files.

Comment: it works when I don't use the flag -o, but it writes the progam in the a.out file. How can I specify a certain name for the output?

Comment: @Jonas Try "-o yourFileName"

Comment: I tried this, it works when I use only one *.cpp file, but if I use mutiple the error occurs again